# Defining a function for FunctionCompile[]

Tags: functions, function-construction, function-compile

Lets say that I have the definition **EQN4** that is determined from some calculation. If I run it in a cell, I get the following output:

```
-((2 (R \[CapitalPhi] + 
    r \[CapitalTheta] \[CapitalPhi] Cot[\[Theta]]))/r)
```

Now I would like to create a function based on **EQN4** which depends on the variables which make up **EQN4**.

```
F8[\[Lambda]_, t_, r_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, T_, R_, \[CapitalTheta]_, \[CapitalPhi]_] := EQN4;
```

Then I can create the function signature for function compilation.

```
dF8=FunctionDeclaration[F8,Typed[{"Real64","Real64","Real64","Real64","Real64","Real64","Real64","Real64","Real64"}->"Real64"]@DownValuesFunction[F8]];
```

And then finally compile the function.

```
RK = FunctionCompile[dF8]
```

However, I get the following errors,

```
Context::ssle: Symbol or string expected at position 1 in Context[-((2 (R \[CapitalPhi]+r \[CapitalTheta] \[CapitalPhi] Cot[\[Theta]]))/r)].
```

```
Compile::err: TypeError. Cannot find a definition for -((2 (R \[CapitalPhi]+r \[CapitalTheta] \[CapitalPhi] Cot[\[Theta]]))/r).
```

```
Failure["TypeError", <|"MessageTemplate" -> "Cannot find a definition \
for `1`.", 
  "MessageParameters" -> {(-2) r^(-1) (
     R \[CapitalPhi] + r \[CapitalTheta] \[CapitalPhi] Cot[\[Theta]])},
   "Body" -> {(-2) r^(-1) (
     R \[CapitalPhi] + r \[CapitalTheta] \[CapitalPhi] Cot[\[Theta]])},
   "Stack" -> {}, "Exception" -> "LookupNotFound", 
  "Constraint" -> TypeFramework`LookupConstraint[], 
  "Source" -> HoldForm[EQN4]|>]
```

I suspect it is because I am not defining **F8** explicitly,

```
F8[\[Lambda]_, t_, r_, \[Theta]_, \[Phi]_, T_, R_, \[CapitalTheta]_, \[CapitalPhi]_] := -((2 (R \[CapitalPhi]+r \[CapitalTheta] \[CapitalPhi] Cot[\[Theta]]))/r);
```

All is good when I define explictly. However, I want to avoid this because **EQN4** varies and can change to something that looks disastrous. So I would like to make the function based off **EQN4** where I dont state explicitly what it is.

Comment: Before compilation, have you actually tried your `F8`, see if it works as expected?